# Set cursor on new created element doesn't work with empty innerHtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

[image: Edit nameless-feather-duk25]

Above you can see code , which I try to making work. The idea here is , I have `contentEditable` div element , in which I type some text , I have button `bold` , which you can click , it will create inside of my `div`, new `strong` element , and will put caret to this element , for giving me opportunity to type in this element . Seems like it put caret to this element , but when I start typing , it types in previos element. How can I put cater in new created element. I also craete it on this element , maybe there is a way to put cater on element by id ? Or any other abailable solution for my case .

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const id = "textarea";

const Buttons = {
  bold: "bold",
  custom: "custom"
};

export default function App() {
  const [button, setButton] = useState();

  const buttons = [
    {
      text: "Bold",
      type: Buttons.bold
    }
  ];

  const onButtonClick = (buttonValue) => {
    if (button === buttonValue) {
      setButton(Buttons.custom);
    } else {
      setButton(buttonValue);
    }
  };

  const prevButton = usePrevious(button);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevButton !== button) {
      const element = document.getElementById(id);

      if (element) {
        console.log(element);

        if (button === Buttons.bold) {
          const strong = document.createElement("strong");
          const id = generateUuid();

          strong.id = id;

          element.appendChild(strong);

          const createdEl = document.getElementById(id);

          const range = document.createRange();
          const sel = document.getSelection();

          if (createdEl) {
            console.log(createdEl, "createdEl");
            range.setStart(createdEl, 0);
            range.setEnd(createdEl, 0);
          }

          if (sel) {
            console.log(sel, "sel");
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, [prevButton, button]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div contentEditable id={id} className="rich-text" />
      {buttons.map((buttonEntity) => {
        return (
          <button onClick={() => onButtonClick(buttonEntity.type)}>
            {buttonEntity.text}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
};

export const generateUuid = () =>
  Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
```

All logic described in `useEffect` by creating new element , and put cater to this element. Important to mention, if you will set some `innerHtml` text to new created element , and will set

```
  range.setStart(createdEl, 1);
  range.setEnd(createdEl, 1);
```

then it will be working , but if no `innerHtml` inside , it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

contenteditable behavior is weird, `element.focus()` doesn't work directly, but it does with a setTimeout(), in some of the cases:

```
const div = document.getElementById('textarea');
setTimeout(() => div.focus(), 0);
```

You might want to add `tabindex=0` to allow users to keyboard navigate into it.

Regardless, using content editable as a full editor will probably give you a bad time, it's a little messy and hard to control. You might want to do this with a hidden input.

Also, this document suggests you can make a rich text editor using content editable,  but it seems deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: it doesn't work , show me working example related to my code pls